# Union polygons in QGIS

Tags: qgis, merge, masking

I have two shapefiles. One contains a raster with grid cells and the other administrative boundaries. 
I would like to *union* the polygons from both layers but geoprocessing - union yields the following error:

```
Processing algorithm…
AlgorithmDialog
Input parameters:
{ 'INPUT' : '/ne_10m_admin_1_states_provinces/ne_10m_admin_1_states_provinces.shp', 'OVERLAY' : 'split.shp', 'OUTPUT' : 'memory:' }

Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.0/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\algs\qgis\Union.py", line 94, in processAlgorithm indexA = QgsSpatialIndex(sourceA, feedback) Exception: unknown 

Execution failed after 0.19 seconds


Loading resulting layers
Algorithm 'Union' finished
```

[image]

Comment: A shapefile is vector file and cannot be a raster "One contains a raster with grid cells and the other administrative boundaries".  Your question is confusing, please clarify.

Comment: Sounds like you want to Intersect them.

Comment: Thanks ... sometimes it's just the buzzword that I am missing. I'll check it out

Comment: I think the buzzwork I am looking for is 'union' (vector - geoprocessing - union)

Answer (score 2):

There are three common reason why a geoprocessing algorithm fails.

1. Incorrect input types. Both input files must be vector layers of the same geometry type.
2. Projection issue. Both input files must be in the same coordinate reference system.
3. Invalid geometries, e.g. duplicate vertex points, self-intersecting polygon border or lines. Use topology checker to find invalid geometries. Fix them manually, or with v.clean command (found in Processing Toolbox under GRASS; must be running "QGIS Desktop with GRASS").